# setInterval with value of 6 seconds executes every 9.5 seconds instead. Why is that?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, settimeout

I have a very simple hook in my React Native application that should console log a string every 6 seconds, however, even though I've set setTimeout to execute every 6000 miliseconds, in reality it executes every 9.5 seconds. I confirmed this with a stopwatch. My hook looks like this:

```
const usePingHeartbeat = () => {
    useEffect(() => {
        const pingHeartbeat = async () => {
            console.log('Pinged');
        };

        const intervalId = setInterval(pingHeartbeat, 6000);

        return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, []);
};

export default usePingHeartbeat;
```

What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

[There are a lot of reasons for delays longer than expected.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout#reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified)

Keeping in mind the event loop, the delay passed as the second argument is the *minimum* delay after which the callback will be added to the message queue. If there is no other message in the queue, and the call stack is empty, the message is processed right after the delay. For this reason, the second argument indicates a minimum time — not a guaranteed time.

Read more about [event loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Event_loop)

So if there are things keeping your single threaded JS busy then yes there will be more delay than you expect